# Extend event listeners within vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently working on a project which uses VueJS. This project has many mixins and components and in the HTML `@click` is defined on many places.

Is it possible to get a list of DOM nodes which has these event listers attached? Or extend the main event listener functionality so that i can add some extra logic to it? I've searched for the answer for hours but still not able to find anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what exactly you want to do. Do you want to intercept every handler assigned by the `v-on` directive?

Comment: one possible approach is using [vue directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#ad), then loop vnode to check whehter any listener exists.

Comment: @Bert Yes that is exactly what i want to do.

Comment: @Sphinx I tried it with a vue directive but i still didn't get it to work.

Comment: I found the solution for my problem, see the answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Great, possible [Vue Source Code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/runtime/modules/events.js) may be helpful for further understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to let you know that after a lot of debugging i found a way to determine what elements have an `@click` event attached. For those who still want to know:

```
function loopThroughVueNodeChildren(children) {
    children.forEach(vnode => {
        // Is an @click attached to this element?
        if (vnode.data && typeof vnode.data.on !== 'undefined' && typeof vnode.data.on.click === 'function') {
            console.log('This element has an @click event! I can do whatever i need to do in here :)');
        }

        if (vnode.children) {
            this.addEventListenerOnVueNodes(vnode.children);
        }
    })
},


loopThroughVueNodeChildren(this._vnode.children);
```